# Why can't I collect the Lines iterator into a vector of Strings?

Tags: string, rust, text-files

I'm trying to read the lines of a text file into a vector of `String`s so I can continually loop over them and write each line to a channel for testing, but the compiler complains about `collect`:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let file = File::open(Path::new("file")).unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(&file);
    let _: Vec<String> = reader.lines().collect().unwrap();
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:9:30
  |
9 |     let lines: Vec<String> = reader.lines().collect().unwrap();
  |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `B`
  |
  = note: type must be known at this point
```

Without the `.unwrap()`, compiler says:

```
error[E0277]: a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>`
 --> src/main.rs:9:45
  |
9 |     let lines: Vec<String> = reader.lines().collect();
  |                                             ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>>`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>`
```

How do I tell Rust the correct type?

Comment: Why the `unwrap()`?

Comment: @ljedrz updated w/o unwrap

Comment: Ah, I forgot it iterated over `Result`s; I'll answer shortly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you want to collect straight into a `Vec<String>` while the `Lines` iterator is over `Result<String, std::io::Error>`, you need to help the type inference a little bit:

```
let lines: Vec<String> = reader.lines().collect::<Result<_, _>>().unwrap();
```

or even just:

```
let lines: Vec<_> = reader.lines().collect::<Result<_, _>>().unwrap();
```

This way the compiler knows that there is an intermediate step with a `Result<Vec<String>, io::Error>`. I think this case could be improved in the future, but for now the type inference is not able to deduce this.

Comment: With the trait [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA%2C%20E%3E%3E), and By the way `String` is inferred.

Comment: `let result: Result<Vec<_>,_> = reader.lines().collect();` this might also be used to if you want to use matcher instead of unwrap. You can still pass expected type as an argument though but imho i would prefer this, looks more clean to me.

Comment: Or `let lines = reader.lines().collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>().unwrap();`

Comment: I get, `the trait `FromIterator<&str>` is not implemented for `Result<_, _>`` when reading a string slice like: 
s: &str = "118\n121\n123"